# How to remove strings which does not belong to HTML tag in an HTML file

Tags: regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML file which contains;

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body><p>thanks god its Friday</p></body>
</html>a&amp; ca-79069608498"
<div class="cont" id="aka"></div>
<footer>
<div class="tent"><div class="cont"></div>
<h2><img alt="dscdsc" height="18" src="dsc.png" srcset="" width="116"/></h2>


</div>
</footer>

 ipt> (window.NORLQ=window.NORLQ||[]).push(function(){var 
ns,i,p,img;ns=document.getElementsByTagName('noscript');for(i=0;i<ns.len)>-1){img=document.createEleight'));img.setAttribute('alt',p.getAttribute('data-alt'));p.parentNode.replaceChild(img,p);}}});/*]]>*/</script><script>(window.RLQ=window.RLQ||[]).push(function(
```

Name of the file is a.html

I want to remove everything after `</html>` in the HTML file using `Python 2.7` but all the strings after HTML tag do not belong to a tag and some of them just noisy so I could not do it using Beautifulsoup and I don't know if it's smart to use regex for HTML file.

How can I remove strings after `</html>` and write to HTML file?

Comment: If the file can be read in full as a single string (including newlines etc), you can search for the position of `</html>` and simply remove everything after that with string indexing.

Comment: thanks a lot also pushed me to learn myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with regex

```
import re
...
newhtml = re.sub('</html>[\s\S.]+', '</html>', oldhtml)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = open(path, "r").read()
b = a.split('</html>', 1)[0]
open(path, 'w').write(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has a module called [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) for dealing this sort of problem.

While the proposed `regexpr` seem to handle your problem well for now, it can be problematic to debug when something went wrong when it cant handle edge cases `HTML`.

Therefore I am proposing a `HTMLParser` solution which gives you more control on its parsing behaviour.

**Example:**

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser


class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    buffer = ""
    end_of_html = False

    def get_html(self):
        return self.buffer

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if not self.end_of_html:
            value = "<" + tag
            for attr in attrs:
                value += attr[0] + "=" + attr[1]
            self.buffer += value + ">"

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if not self.end_of_html:
            self.buffer += data

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if not self.end_of_html:
            self.buffer += "</" + tag + ">"
        if tag == "html":
            self.end_of_html = True


parser = MyHTMLParser();
parser.feed("""<html>
</div>
<head></head>
<body><p>thanks god its Friday</p></body>
</html>a&amp; ca-79069608498"
<div class="cont" id="aka"></div>
<footer>
<div class="tent"><div class="cont"></div>
<h2><img alt="dscdsc" height="18" src="dsc.png" srcset="" width="116"/></h2>


</div>
</footer>

 ipt> (window.NORLQ=window.NORLQ||[]).push(function(){var
ns,i,p,img;ns=document.getElementsByTagName('noscript');for(i=0;i<ns.len)>-1){img=document.createEleight'));img.setAttribute('alt',p.getAttribute('data-alt'));p.parentNode.replaceChild(img,p);}}});/*]]>*/</script><script>(window.RLQ=window.RLQ||[]).push(function(
        """)

print parser.get_html()
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
</div>
<head></head>
<body><p>thanks god its Friday</p></body>
</html>
```